# How to autoboot boot0?

Tags: freebsd, dual-boot, boot-loader

How can automatically boot FreeBSD in `boot0` and, when needed, manually load win by pressing a shortcut button?

Comment: Did you try boot0cfg from FreeBSD to configure default slice? Also set non-update mode so the last selection isn't recorded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow solve this by `boot0cfg -t 18` *device*  that automatically boot in 18 ticks (about 1 second).